# Chromatic number of a $K_r$-free graph

Tags: graph-theory

How large can be the chromatic number of a $K_r$-free graph--a graph with clique number at most $r-1$, compared to the number of its vertices? I am particularly interested in any good upper bound for the case $r=4$.

Comment: Already for triangle free graphs, their chromatic number can be arbitrarily large. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mycielskian

Comment: Yes! Sorry for the error. It has been fixed.

Comment: See [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2525544/383078) of mine for the general idea: you reduce upper-bounding the chromatic number to lower-bounding the independence number, which in turn is equivalent to upper-bounding the Ramsey numbers $R(r,s)$ for fixed $r$. (In the linked answer, we obtain the not-very-good answer of $O(n^{2/3})$, but better Ramsey bounds give correspondingly better chromatic number bounds.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For $r\geq 3$, and for any $n\in\mathbb{N}$ there is a [triangle-free graphs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triangle-free_graph) $G$ such that $\chi(G)\geq n$. So the chromatic number can become arbitrarily large. (Of course this doesn't hold for $k \leq 2$ because $K_2$-free graphs have no edges.)

Comment: Thank you very much for your time. Here, in this question, I am interested in an upper bound (possibly sharp upper bound) on the number of the vertices of a given $K_r$-free graph

Comment: For example, it is not hard to see that:  For every $K_3$-free graph $G$ of order $n$, $\chi(G) \leq 2\sqrt{n} +1$.

Comment: @MathFun Following the links in the Wikipedia paged Dominic posted, this paper says that the sharp bound for $G$ $K_3$-free of order $n$ is $\chi(G) \leq O (\sqrt{n/\log n})$. http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0012365X0000087X?via%3Dihub

Comment: I found this (see (53)) http://www.math.uri.edu/~eaton/One.pdf

Comment: @WillSawin Thanks for sharing the link! Is there such a result for $r=4$ also?